# Detect when fragment becomes visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Why not a duplicate:** Suggested post only works for a viewpager, or when onResume is called.

I have a listfragment and a detailfragment. The detail fragment is opened when a list item is clicked. I accomplish this by hiding the listfragment and I showing the detailfragment. When the user goes back, he returns to the listfragment.

How can I detect when the user gets back to my fragment, or when my fragment is visible?

Please note that I would like to keep using .hide() and show() and that I am looking for a listener or a onVisible to check *when* the fragment *becomes* visible, and not a method to check *if* it is visible.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use hide and show?. I would use Fragment Transactions and just check the stack count, e.g. If it's 1 it means your detail fragment is visible, if not, the listfragment is.

Comment: Why do you prefer to use hide() and show() instead of fragment transactions and back stack? It might be easier to accomplish what you need following the guidelines...

Comment: @Elenasys This applies for a viewpager where setuservisiblehint can be used

Comment: Does `onHiddenChanged()` fire for your fragments?

Comment: If you could provide me some info on how to use to detect if my fragment is visible again, that would be awesome. I'll check if it gets called asop, but I feel think this might work!

Comment: According to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean) it will be called if the hidden state changes. Beware because it states that it will not be called on the first start of the fragment, but on subsequent state changes

Comment: Let me know if it works, in case it does I'll edit my answer for others to see in the future.

Comment: Yes, it gets called. When I open detailfragment from listfragment & when I go back to listfragment. So I'll then I'll only have to check if the fragment is currently visible.

Comment: Ok great. I edited my answer so all information is in one place.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, `setUserVisbileHint()` does not get called automatically, but by the FragmentPageAdapter when used in a ViewPager.

For the scenario described in the question, `onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean) is suitable.
As stated in the documentation, the method gets called every time the Fragments hidden state changes, but not on the initial setup of the Fragment.

---

<s>You could use `setUserVisibleHint()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)</s>

if `isVisibleToUser`is set to `true`the fragment should be displayed.

Comment: This method gets called once the Fragment becomes visible. I use it in a ViewPager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731589/is-fragment-setuservisiblehint-called-by-the-android-system - "the answer to the question clearly: you call it manually, and FragmentPagerAdapter also calls it manually"

Comment: Ok thanks, didn't know that the FragmentPagerAdapter calls it. Learned something.

Answer (score -1):

Read about the method : **[Fragment. isVisible()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible%28%29)**

Example:

```
MyFragmentClass test = (MyFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById("myFragnmentID");
if (test != null && test.isVisible()) {
     //VISIBLE! =)
}
else {
    //NOT VISIBLE =(
}
```

Comment: This is to check if it is visible (by calling this code). But I would like to be notified when the fragment becomes visible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731589/is-fragment-setuservisiblehint-called-by-the-android-system

Comment: neighbors in the view pager are always reported as visible

Answer (score -2):

You could send an event to your activity when the fragment is started : 
https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-android-mednieks-1st/chapter-11/visualizing-the-fragment-life

By overriding the onStart method :

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((MyInterface)getActivity()).onFragmentIsVisible( this );
}
```

Where `MyInterface`is an interface :

```
public MyInterface {
   public void onFragmentVisible( Fragment fragment );
}
```

and your activity will have to implement it.

This could be more easy with an event bus library like

- [RoboGuice's event bus](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Events)
- [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)
- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: I'll try your code, but please note that onStart is not called when the fragment becomes visible again

Comment: Have you tried `onResume` so ?

Comment: onRsume() & onStart() only called in fragment if parent activity methods called, so no need to implement other Interface for callback.