# Android: How to find out when coming back from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an app that uses fragments and when one fragment opens it changes the app title to a certain string, everything works fine but when I press the back button and go back to the main fragment the title doesn't change.

How can i find out (from the main fragment) if the app is coming back from a fragment?

Comment: What about setting title in main fragment's onResume?

Comment: or you can override the back button managing everything there

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28031401/1860982

Comment: check this, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21733717/4700782

Answer (score 1):

If you already added your fragments into backstack, by using:

```
addToBackStack(null);
```

Then, when you back pressed from a fragment,  you can add OnBackStackChangedListener for your FragmentManager:

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                // check if the current fragment is the fragment you want.
                //then, updating your title.
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using

```
getActivity().setTitle("title");
```

in the onDestroy() of the fragment