# true answer for detecting fragment when become visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

how detect when fragment becomes visible ,i searched for this question and got many answers .

1 . use `setUserVisibleHint()` : this method is not invoke all times and does not get called automatically. for example i created this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setUserVisibleHint(false);
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (isResumed()){
        if (isVisibleToUser){//fragment visible
            load();
        }else{
            //content.listener.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

this method is not invoked for first item in viewPager . it mean this is not worked truly .

2 . use `onHiddenChanged()` : this answer was true but now it's not working . I checked this code in fragment . but this is not invoking sometimes.

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    Log.e(TAG , "   "+hidden);
}
```

3 . some idea for paging in viewPager like `setOnPageChangeListener` : pay attention , i want true answer in fragment for all times . not just for viewPager or other views

i got answers in these links anad ... :

[How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

[Detect when fragment becomes visible [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733355/detect-when-fragment-becomes-visible)

any one can help me by true answer?

Comment: stackoverflow auto detect this tag . :)

Comment: Yeah . . . . .  . . . .

Comment: yeah . that's true . but i think that's better to not change system tag

Answer (score 0):

I use setUserVisibleHint and it perfectly working for me. I think you forget to give **super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);** within setUserVisibleHint function.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //When fragment is visible
    }
}
```

Hope so it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: thank for you answer . but again thats not detect visible auto