# Fragment does not call setUserVisibleHint

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanted to print out text whenever user sees Fragment X.

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Testing!")
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
}
```

But `setUserVisibleHint()` never gets called. Why is that?

My fragment is standart `class FragmentX: Fragment()` and I use

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more easily if you provide a [mcve]. Anyone should be able to copy/paste your code and then compile and run it without any errors.

Comment: You should also try google and you would find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269836/android-setuservisiblehint-never-gets-called

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Read the post, but it clearly did not help in my case.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to explain why that answer did not help you.

Comment: are you using kotlin..??

Comment: @ByeWebster Seems so :)

Comment: maybe this is will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269174/how-to-tell-when-fragment-is-not-visible-in-a-navigationdrawer