# on popBackStack() which method invoked in previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have Fragment A.
On clicking some button, i add Fragment B above Fragment A.

```
    FragmentB fragmentB= new FragmentB ();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_home, fragmentB, "fragmentB");
    fragmentTransaction.hide(FragmentA.this);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentA.class.getName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I perform some action in Fragment B. After finishing my work i popBackStack() current fragment.

```
  FragmentManager   fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Now i Fragment A. Since i used "ADD fragment" all my values are kept in edittext.

I want to know, which method is invoked when i come back to Fragment A, 
is it onResume()..?
I have to put log in onResume, seems like it not going to onResume!

Comment: **setuservisiblehint** method will be called whenever the fragment become visible to the user

Comment: @RahulKhurana i will try this and let you know! :)

Comment: @RahulKhurana  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20657022/3348373 according to this link, setUserVisibleHint() is called in  fragments put in a pager.! I override setUserVisibleHint() and it wasn't called

Comment: Have a look at this [fragment lifecycle] ( https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ePcpvCCqKgY/UhODSSrFHoI/AAAAAAAAAoM/uq6Y9aWvh-cLGoao9DFy5K6zJ-NZzrDIA/w506-h930/android_fragment_lifecycle_complete.png )

Answer (score 0):

instead of `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_home, fragmentB, "fragmentB");`
use

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_home, fragmentB, "fragmentB");
```

refer link [Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

try below code

```
FragmentB fragmentB= new FragmentB ();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_home, fragmentB, "fragmentB");
    fragmentTransaction.hide(FragmentA.this);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentA.class.getName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Fragment documentation, your fragment will be resumed after pressing back. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

> if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment,
>   then the fragment is stopped and will be resumed if the user navigates
>   back.

But you said,

> I have to put log in onResume, seems like it not going to onResume!

Then you may have some problems in your code: 
 - If you do

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(FragmentA.this);
```

then you may need to use FragmentTransaction.show(Fragment), in order to display FragmentA again. And then it will go to onResume().