# How to tell when fragment is not visible in a NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, android-view

I am trying to tell when a user selects a different fragment in my navigation drawer. I was trying to use

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
}
```

How i switch fragments in my MainActivity:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.nav_camera -> {
                // Handle the camera action
                val fragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit()

            }
            R.id.nav_manage -> {
                val fragment: SettingFragment = SettingFragment()
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit()

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {
                onInviteClicked()

            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {

                val emailIntent: Intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                emailIntent.type = Constants.FEEDBACK_EMAIL_TYPE

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        arrayOf(Constants.FEEDBACK_EMAIL_ADDRESS))

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        Constants.FEEDBACK_EMAIL_SUBJECT)

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                        emailIntent, Constants.FEEDBACK_TITLE))


            }
        }

        val drawer: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

However this does not seem to get called at all. For example, in my `NavigationDrawer` activity, it shows Fragment A. The user opens the navigation drawer and selects Fragment B. `setUserVisibleHint()` does not get called in fragment A so my code can know it is no longer shown. I need my code that is isolated in fragment A to know when it is not shown so it can call .stop() on some variables. This is the same use case as onPause() in an activity.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Why not using with the Navigation Drawer directly? I mean, you know that the user has selected the Fragment B, so you know what has happenned. So what not to put your logic in the onClickListener of the Navigation Drawer. Like that you'll know what is displayed or not without trying to guess it from the Fragment's state. But are you sure your Fragment A is not displayed btw?

Can you had the code of the Navigation Drawer listener?

Comment: Please post more code, Where are you calling this function? what does your activity look like?

Comment: @Eselfar  i have added more info onto why i need it like this.

Comment: So why not calling `.stop` in the `onPause` of the Fragment as the fragment is paused when not displayed? Still don't understand your issue.

Comment: @Eselfar onPause only gets called in a fragment when its activity onPause get called. It doesnt get called when its out of view

Comment: How do you switch your fragment?

Comment: @BakaWaii i updated with code on how i switch fragments

Comment: Did you try to put the code in `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`? I think it should work.

Comment: you are calling both `supportFragmentManager` and `fragmentManager`, is that supported?  also `setUserVisibleHint` had issues in several early SDK levels, not sure which level called it fixed.

Comment: you could have a look aat one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384809/configure-a-fragment-to-be-shown-first-when-application-is-started/45384948#45384948)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things I can think of...

1. Use a consistent fragment, either Support or Native, not both.  And, some say the Support fragment is preferable (better maintained).
2. Make sure the fragment container is not hard coded in XML.  If you intend to replace a fragment, then the initial fragment should be loaded dynamically by your code (you typically will load into a FrameLayout using the id as your R.id.{frameLayoutId}).
3. **Do Use** the Frament lifecycle events.  `onPause` fires when you replace a fragment, so does `onDetach`.  That will tell you when your old fragment is no longer visible (or will be invisible shortly). If it does not fire, then you have another issue in your code, possibly mixing of Fragment types, or a hardcoded fragment in XML?
4. Use `setUserVisibleHint` only in a fragment pager, or be prepared to set it manually.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731589/is-fragment-setuservisiblehint-called-by-the-android-system) answer has a little more to say about the use of `setUserVisibleHint`.  When using a pager, multiple fragments can be attached at once, so an additional means (some call it lifecycle event) was needed to tell if a fragment was "really, truly" visible, hence `setUserVisibleHint` was introduced.
5. **Bonus**: If appropriate for your app, use the back stack for backing up by calling `addToBackStack` after `replace`.  I add this mainly as an addition lifecycle item one would typically want in their app.  The code looks like this...

   ```
   // to initialize your fragment container
   supportFragmentManager
           .beginTransaction()
           .add(R.id.content_fragment, fragment)
           .addToBackStack("blank")
           .commit()

   // to update your fragment container
   supportFragmentManager
           .beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment)
           .addToBackStack("settings")
           .commit()

   //in your XML, it can be as simple as adding the FrameLayout below,
   // if you start with the Android Studio template for Navigation drawer,
   // you can replace the call that includes the "content_main" layout

   <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" /> -->
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/content_fragment" />
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I would add specifically to use the PreferenceFragmentCompat to use with the supportfragmentmanager. That was the issue since i was using both Native and Support fragment managers

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call

```
if (myFragment.isVisible()) {...}
```

or another way is

```
public boolean isFragmentUIActive() {
    return isAdded() && !isDetached() && !isRemoving();
}
```

Comment: Since this is not an overriden method i would have to have an infinite loop constantly checking if the fragment is visible or not, this would not be ideal.